# Azure Durable Function does not respond and error out at the end

Tags: azure-durable-functions, azurite

I followed these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-isolated-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-visualstudio) to create a `Durable Function App`. I use `Netherite` as the durable storage provider. When I send a POST request to the Orchestrator function, the call does not return for a minute or so. Sometimes I get the following error:

```
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.163Z] Function 'Function1_HttpStart', Invocation id '5f555cfc-6a1c-48c3-9b4b-57f72c4018f2': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.165Z] Result: Function 'Function1_HttpStart', Invocation id '5f555cfc-6a1c-48c3-9b4b-57f72c4018f2': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="", DebugException="System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.165Z]  ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.166Z]  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.166Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.<>c.<WaitForDataAsync>b__87_0(Object s, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.166Z]    at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(Boolean throwOnFirstException)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.167Z]    at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean isThreadPool)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.167Z]    at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.167Z]    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.168Z]    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.168Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.168Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.169Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadResponseHeadersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.169Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.169Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.170Z]    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.170Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.170Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.171Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.171Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.171Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.172Z]    at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)"))
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.172Z]  ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="", DebugException="System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.173Z]  ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.173Z]  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.173Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.<>c.<WaitForDataAsync>b__87_0(Object s, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.174Z]    at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(Boolean throwOnFirstException)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.174Z]    at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean isThreadPool)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.174Z]    at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.175Z]    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.175Z]    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.175Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.176Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.176Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadResponseHeadersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.176Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.177Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.177Z]    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.177Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.178Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.178Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.178Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.180Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.181Z]    at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.181Z]    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Client.Grpc.GrpcDurableTaskClient.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(TaskName orchestratorName, Object input, StartOrchestrationOptions options, CancellationToken cancellation)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.181Z]    at MyAPI.Function1.HttpStart(HttpRequestData req, DurableTaskClient client, FunctionContext executionContext) in C:\My Projects\MyAPI\MyAPI\Function1.cs:line 45
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.182Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.182Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.182Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.183Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.<>c.<InvokeAsync>b__6_0(Task`1 t) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 32
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.183Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.183Z]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.184Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.184Z]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.184Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.185Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.185Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1_HttpStart' (Failed, Id=5f555cfc-6a1c-48c3-9b4b-57f72c4018f2, Duration=100228ms)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.185Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 45
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.185Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.Function1_HttpStart. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="", DebugException="System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.186Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.186Z]  ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.187Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext functionContext, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.cs:line 22
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.187Z]  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.187Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77
Stack:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.188Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.<>c.<WaitForDataAsync>b__87_0(Object s, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.188Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.188Z]    at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(Boolean throwOnFirstException)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.189Z]    at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean isThreadPool)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.189Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.<>c.<InvokeAsync>b__6_0(Task`1 t) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 32
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.190Z]    at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.190Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.191Z]    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.191Z]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.191Z]    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.192Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.192Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.192Z]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.193Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.193Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.193Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadResponseHeadersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.194Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.194Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.194Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 45
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.195Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.196Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.197Z]    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.197Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext functionContext, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.cs:line 22
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.197Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.198Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.198Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.199Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.199Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.200Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.200Z]    at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)"))
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.200Z]  ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="", DebugException="System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.201Z]  ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.201Z]  ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.201Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.<>c.<WaitForDataAsync>b__87_0(Object s, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.202Z]    at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(Boolean throwOnFirstException)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.202Z]    at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean isThreadPool)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.203Z]    at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.203Z]    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.203Z]    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.204Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.204Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.204Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadResponseHeadersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.205Z]    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.205Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.205Z]    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.206Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.206Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.207Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.207Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.207Z]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.208Z]    at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.208Z]    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Client.Grpc.GrpcDurableTaskClient.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(TaskName orchestratorName, Object input, StartOrchestrationOptions options, CancellationToken cancellation)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.208Z]    at MyAPI.Function1.HttpStart(HttpRequestData req, DurableTaskClient client, FunctionContext executionContext) in C:\My Projects\MyAPI\MyAPI\Function1.cs:line 45
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.209Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.209Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.209Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.210Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.<>c.<InvokeAsync>b__6_0(Task`1 t) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 32
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.210Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.210Z]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.211Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.211Z]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.213Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.213Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.214Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 45
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.214Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.214Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext functionContext, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.cs:line 22
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.215Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.215Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88
Stack:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.215Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.216Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionInvoker`2.<>c.<InvokeAsync>b__6_0(Task`1 t) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionInvoker.cs:line 32
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.216Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.216Z]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.217Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.217Z]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.217Z]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.218Z] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.218Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultFunctionExecutor.cs:line 45
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.218Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.219Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext functionContext, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in /_/src/Worker.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskFunctionsMiddleware.cs:line 22
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.219Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 77
[2023-07-26T12:02:42.219Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88.
```

The `Azurite Storage Explorer` does not display any data:

[image]

I see continuous output in the command shell where I ran `Azurite`:

[image]

I have successfully run `Azure Function App` locally without any problem before. The problem is with the `Durable Function App` only. How can I make the function calls work and see the response in the `Storage Explorer`?

I see thousands of these messages in the `Azurite` command prompt. The message is `PUT /devstoreaccount1/testhubname-storage?restype=container HTTP/1.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Without much luck for the `Durable Function` to work, I finally uninstalled Visual Studio Community Edition and separate installs I made for `Azurite`. I deleted the folder for `Storage Explorer`. I reinstalled Visual Studio Community Edition, Azure Storage Explorer. Now I can run durable function endpoint in Postman and receive responses.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.
Didn't wanted to hustle with the studio reinstall, so I opened the project I created in VS Professional in VS Code. Installed Azurite and some azure related extensions, that VSC automatically prompted I'll need for function debugging. (Prompt happens, when you hit F5 to try to run the project)

Debugging the project from VSC runs the durable functions without any issue.